# Starting settimeout immediately an event happens

Tags: javascript

I have some code that uses `setTimeout` to launch and close a sweetalert dialog after some 15 seconds. I am running the code when an event has happened but i am having to wait an initial 15 seconds before the code begins to run.

Is there a way i can start the `setTimeout` duration immediately the event happens without waiting 15 seconds?  This is my code

```
function myFunction() {
      Swal.fire({
          title: "Processing Payment",
          html: "<img src='https://www.boasnotas.com/img/loading2.gif' height='30px' />",
          buttons: false,
          closeOnClickOutside: false,
          timer: 15000
      })
  }

  function clearTimer() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      //Swal.close();
  }

  var timer = setTimeout(function () {
      myFunction();
      clearTimer();
      //Swal.close();
  }, 15000);
```

Comment: I don't think that you need to use `setTimeout()`. The `timer` property already handles the auto close of the popup.

Comment: Thats the easy part. Can i attach a callback to sweetalert to check if some event has happened inside the 15 seconds and poll this every 5 seconds? That the whole point of having the seperate timeout.

Answer (score 2):

The [`timer`](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#timer) property should do the trick. Here is an example of an auto close after 1.5s.

It might not work because of the options you use. Indeed, as you can see in the console log, `buttons` and `closeOnClickOutside` are not valid parameters :

```js
function myFunction() {
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Processing Payment",
        html: "<img src='https://www.boasnotas.com/img/loading2.gif' height='30px' />",
        buttons: false,
        closeOnClickOutside: false,
        timer: 1500
    })
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Can i pass a call back to swal to poll for an event every 5 seconds but inside those 15 seconds?

Comment: @Gandalf, comments are made to ask for a clarification or for more informations about a question or an answer. You should ask this in another question so that if anyone has the same problem, the solution would be easier to find.

Comment: Like you didn't literally copy the code i had and answered your own question!

Comment: See [this example](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#timer-example) and update it to fit to your case ...

Answer (score 2):

But you don't need to use clear(), Swal's time function starts and closes itself when you call it.

doc:https://sweetalert2.github.io/

exemplo:Swal.fire({
position: 'top-end',
icon: 'success',
title: 'Your work has been saved',
showConfirmButton: false,
timer: 1500
})

the timer is the duration time, it's easier for you to control it here